# Why am I getting an error that says Property assignment expected when I'm not even using TypeScript?

Tags: react-native

My Code is

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

const ComponentsScreen = () => {
  return {
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.testStyle}>This is the components screen</Text>
    </View>
    };
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    testStyle: {
        fontSize: 30
    }
});

export default ComponentsScreen;
```

I am getting an error which says Property Assignment Expected at my opening View tag, Declaration or Statement expected error at my closing View tag and at the bracket which closes ComponentsScreen, and Expression expected at the bracket closing my return statement. Any solutions?

Comment: what happens if you use parenthesis `(...)` instead of braces `{}` in the return statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In component screen jsx uses return statment in parantheses rather than curly braces {} .

So just replace this :

```
const ComponentsScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.testStyle}>This is the components screen</Text>
    </View>
    );
};
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Answer (score 1):

```
return {
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.testStyle}>This is the components screen</Text>
    </View>
}
```

this will return an object.
You should return an JSX.Element instead.

try

```
return (
<View>
    <Text style={styles.testStyle}>This is the components screen</Text>
</View>)
```