# Sending a variable through python flask to javascript and displaying bar graph using google charts

Tags: python, html, flask, google-visualization

Hey i am trying to make a bar graph in my html page. I am using Google Charts, flask and html. Whenever I manually enter data it works perfectly. But when I try to send the data through flask, it doesn't show anything.

Here is my application.py:

```
import flask
import mysql.connector

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

f = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "")
mycur = f.cursor()

@app.route("/")
def get_vals():
    mycur.execute("use one_stop_healthcare;")
    mycur.execute("select NAME, ACTIVE, DISCHARGED from ccinfo;")
    dat = mycur.fetchall()

    active=[[]]
    for i in range(0,5,1):
        for j in range(0,2,1):
            active[i].append(dat[i][j])
        active.append([])
    del active[5]
    active.insert(0, ['All the wards', 'Active cases', 'Recovered'])
    print(active)
    return flask.render_template("index.html", active=active)

app.run()
```

Here is my index.html(In a template folder)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMultSeries);
        var active
        function drawMultSeries() {
// Here is where i manually add the data. It works like this.
            var active = [['All the wards', 'Active cases', 'Recovered'], ['Ward-1', 357, 153], ['Ward-2', 744, 349], ['Ward-3', 83, 54], ['Ward-4', 1360, 433], ['Ward-5', 149, 100]]
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(active);

        var options = {
            title: 'Covid care centers',
            chartArea: {width: '50%'},
            hAxis: {
            title: 'Active cases',
            minValue: 0
            },
            vAxis: {
            title: 'Wards'
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You currently don't use the python object 'active' at all.

Replace this line in your html-code:

```
var active
```

by

```
var active = {{active}}
```

(and remove the manuall declaration)

Comment: @loaTzimas i tried your suggestion but it seemed to give an error for the brackets.

Comment: Strange. Can you please paste the line of your code that gives the error?

Comment: var active = {{active}} There is a red line coming under one of the curly braces

Comment: What does this red line say? Maybe there is some inconsistency of your brackets in your JS code?

Comment: Property assignment expected and Declaration or statement expected.

Comment: Are you sure the code runs properly with the manual declaration? Maybe you need to add some return to your JS function? Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60234311/why-am-i-getting-an-error-that-says-property-assignment-expected-when-im-not-ev

Comment: Yes it works when i add the data manually. I also ensured that the data format is exactly same to what is required